# Ubuntu 20.04 Steam wont start STEAM_RUNTIME_HEAVY: ./steam-runtime-heavy

Tags: apt, steam

All of a sudden Steam won't open. I've not made any changes to Steam or the system, apart from software updates which are run daily.

I've tried running steam from the CLI but get the following:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
/home/mark/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam -nominidumps -nobreakpad
[2021-06-10 13:30:59] Startup - updater built Jun  8 2021 22:23:36
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2021-06-10 13:30:59] Loading cached metrics from disk (/home/mark/.steam/package/steam_client_metrics.bin)
[2021-06-10 13:30:59] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2021-06-10 13:30:59] 1. https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 100, source = 'update_hosts_cached.vdf'
[2021-06-10 13:30:59] 2. https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 100, source = 'update_hosts_cached.vdf'
[2021-06-10 13:30:59] 3. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2021-06-10 13:30:59] Checking for update on startup
[2021-06-10 13:30:59] Checking for available updates...
[2021-06-10 13:30:59] Downloading manifest: https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2021-06-10 13:30:59] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1623193086, installed version 1623193086, existing pending version 0
[2021-06-10 13:30:59] Nothing to do
[2021-06-10 13:30:59] Verifying installation...
[2021-06-10 13:30:59] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2021-06-10 13:31:00] Verification complete
STEAM_RUNTIME_HEAVY: ./steam-runtime-heavy
```

I've tried removing steam `sudo apt purge steam` and then reinstalling Steam fresh `sudo apt install steam` yet I still get the exact same error.

What can I do? Are there any possible logs I should be looking for?

Comment: Looks like the normal startup, I see no errors.  Is there a steam icon in the title bar?  Any red dot next to steam launchpad icon (when not started from terminal)?  Any  processes shown with ps auxww |fgrep -i steam   ?

Comment: Have you tried to restart your PC? If graphics drivers have been updated sometimes Steam refuses to launch without a reboot.

Comment: I have exactly the same issues since today.

Comment: Same problem just popped up for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coming from this Github issue:
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/7813

For me, this was a bug when using the "Remember me" checkbox option for Steam login, combined with having a large number of network interfaces (because of Docker for example).

That leaves two options:

- Don't check the "Remember me" checkbox at account login; or
- Resolve your large number of network interfaces (with `docker network prune` for example, if you're sure you don't need those).

In either case, I had to delete my ~/.steam directory in order to get the Steam login dialog to launch again. That also meant redownloading my games.

Comment: For me running `docker network prune` worked, without having to delete the `~/.steam` directly (I however started Steam with `steam -reset` beforehand, not sure if this helped).

Comment: Yeah, it's probably worth trying `steam --reset` first, though in my case it didn't seem to help.

Comment: @LesLim absolute madness but yeah that was the problem

Comment: Sorted! Well that's pretty nuts!